# formatting output from tail -f

Tags: grep, printf, tail

I'm trying to follow a log-file via tail -f and filtering it with grep:

`tail -f <log-file> | grep -F '<some string>'`

I want the output to be updated at the same line instead of getting new lines on
the stdout. This means there is only one line of output at the stdout that's changing whenever grep finds a match.

I tried to filter the newline respectively adding a carriage return with several commands like `prinft, sed, awk, echo` but didn't get it work.
I'm on an AIX-machine, so not every manpage option of grep or other commands are supported.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
tail -f <logfile> | awk '/some string/{system("");printf "\r%s", $0}'
```

`system("")` is a little hack to avoid buffering.

Comment: Not for me. Only one line. Maybe use bash instead of another shell

Comment: I'm currently using the bash. Maybe this is a Problem of AIX?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `watch` installed?  If I understood what you're asking for (and I'm not sure I did), you could run something like this:

`watch "tail -f <log-file> | grep -F '<some string>'"`

Comment: unfortunately I don't have the file permissions in order to work with watch, the system told me so.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that watch requires special permissions.  Can you copy and paste the error message that you get?

Comment: Maybe I described it a little bit inexact, the problem seems to be that my permissions do not allow the use of the watch binary itself: 
watch --help --> -bash: /usr/sbin/watch: The file access permissions do not allow the specified action.

Comment: /usr/sbin/watch on AIX is not the watch twm means. Look at http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cmds%2Fdoc%2Faixcmds6%2Fwatch.htm .